# Platform target at Any CPU or x64 locks files

Tags: c#, wpf, file, locking

I noticed that when you set the Platform target in Visual Studio to Any CPU / x64 some files are getting locked (e.g. aticfx64.dll, which is a device driver file for AMD display). However, with the Platform target on x86 no files are locked.

We need the Platform target at Any CPU, but we don't want these files locked. I already went on the internet, but couldn't find anything about this issue. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this or came across a similar problem? Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different lists of `AppInit_DLLs` in the registry for 32-bit and 64-bit applications.  In general, DLL injection is different depending on process bitness.

You might want to double-check that the registry list of preload DLLs and remove any you don't want.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what my issue has to do with dll injection. In case you are wondering, the only entry in the AppInit_DLLs is guard.dll.

Comment: @Phyxion: The most likely reason the DLL is locked is that it was loaded into the process by injection.  Can you use e.g. Process Explorer to look at the list of loaded DLLs?

Comment: Thank you, now I understand your answer. And yes, the dll is there indeed (amongst a long list of other dlls). That said, is it fixable? I certainly don't want these dlls to load. FYI, I don't reference them, as they are somehow loaded at runtime.

Comment: I managed to unload it by using the FreeLibrary + GetModuleHandle functions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That said, it crashes on several FreeLibrary calls (probably because the DLLs are used). The real question still remains, how to prevent those files from getting loaded?

Comment: @Phyxion: That probably depends on each particular DLL.  One way would be to delete those DLLs off your computer entirely (or rename them so they can't be found by whatever technique is injecting them).

Comment: I'm aware that it's a possibility, but I'm not looking at the removal of those files or to rename them (as they are used by the display driver). I just don't want to be injected in my program.

Comment: @Phyxion: Those aren't used by the display driver.  They're part of the software bundled with your display driver, intended to be injected into programs to add "extra features", like the Catalyst Control Center link in the right-click menu of the open files dialog.

Comment: Thanks :) Either way, I still don't want them to be loaded in my application. Is there anyway to prevent that from happening?